# How do I put the character '&' in 6th column and 80th column in vi

Tags: vim, vi

I am using vi as the editor of choice for Fortran programming. Sometimes, I want to replace the 6th and 80th characters of a certain line with `&`. For example in the fortran program:

```
       Program Test
       real*8 x
c
       write(*,*)
     1   'Hello World'  
     2   , x
        end
```

the characters `1` and `2` are supposed be replaced by an `&` not in the whole file but on the 'current line'. Can I create a function or a "hot key" for this? In addition, I want to put another `&` in the 80th column.

Comment: Do you mean 7th column? The `1` and `2` above are in column 7 (vim, like most editors, counts columns beginning with 1).

Comment: oh that is a formatting problem while typig the question. I do mean 1 and 2 should be in the 6th

Answer (score 1):

Two approaches

```
:s/\v(.){79}\zs./\&
```

Or

```
80|r&
```

Where `80|` jumps to the 80th column.

Most will store this latter possibility into a macro. It can stored into a mapping as well (`:nnoremap µ 80|r&`).

However, if there aren't that many characters, you'll have to either complete the line, or more simply to work with the option `'virtualedit'` set to `all`.

Comment: although it is easy, can I name `80|r&` to a more readable name in vimrc or something?

Comment: 80| jumps to end of line which is before column 80

Comment: It's up to you to find a keybinding you'll remember. In my answer I've proposed `µ`. It can be whatever you want. Regarding the end of line, the simplest solution is to `:set virtualedit=all`. Otherwise, we'd have to append `repeat(' ', 80-col('$')).'&'`, or do the replacement depending on `col('$')` value.

Comment: i.e. something like: `:nnoremap <expr> <special> µ (col('$') < 80 ? 'A'.repeat(' ', 80-col('$')).'&<esc>' : '80\|r&')`. Setting `'virtualedit'` is definitively simpler -- NB: the backslash is required because of `:h bar`issues.

Answer (score 0):

You can go to column with `|` and replace a single character with `r`. Say you want change column '6' to '&'. You can do `6|r&`.

You can do the same to change 80th column to '&' given 80th column exist. I would recommend doing 'A &' instead (adding '&' add the end of line).

For a quick function in `.vimrc`:

```
nnoremap <silent> <F8> 06 r&3<ESC>A &<ESC>
```

(Maps F8 to hot key. '0' goes to beginning of the line. Then 6 spaces. Replace character under cursor with '&'.  to finish first part. 'A' to append ' &' at the end and  once more).

Then just press F8 on the line desired.

Comment: do I type `<-E-S-C->` or the escape key?

Comment: You need "<ESC>" (the whole thing) in your .vimrc. The "<>" tells vim to use specific key when function is executed. You can insert (or copy paste) the whole line in .vimrc.